# How to create multiple jQuery dialogs in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to generate multiple jQuery Dialogs within a loop. Funny thing is, if I hardcode the dialogs in the `function()`, like `#dialog1.dialog({...})` and `#dialog2.dialog({...})` and so on it works!
But if I generate these functions in a loop it doesn't work!!!
Here is an exemplary code:

```
<div id=object><div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var  array =['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'];
$(document).ready(function () {
    for(var i = 0; i < 7 ; i++) {
        $( "#dialog"+array[i]).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: "auto",
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 500
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 500
            }
        });

        $( "#opener"+array[i]).click(function() {
            $( "#dialog"+array[i]).dialog( "open" );
        }); 
     }
});

for(var i = 0; i < 7 ; i++) {
    $("#object").append("<button id=\opener"+array[i]+">Details</button> ");
    $("#object").append("<div class=\"dialog\" id=\"dialog"+array[i]+"\"title=\"Details\"></div>");
};

</script> `
```

It would be very kind if someone could help me!

Comment: You're adding the buttons after you've added the listeners.  Have a look at "delegated events" for jQuery.  Also you can just replace i in place of `array[i]` and change your for loop to `for(var i = 1; i =< 8 ; i++)`

Comment: @RobSchmuecker: No he's not. The listeners are in the doc.ready, while the adding of dynamic elements is not. (@)OP: The code seems okay... What if you change the `.dialog()` call with a simple `alert(i);`? Do all boxes get shown? Also, your for loop should be `for(var i = 0; i < 8 ; i++)` since you have 8 items in the array :)

Comment: @RobSchmuecker: `for(var i = 1; i =< 8 ; i++)` would be for an 1-based array, or you'd force the constant usage of `i-1`.

Comment: @Flater He does indeed add the listeners before the buttons check http://jsfiddle.net/3Tp35/ as for the 1-based array that is what his code is doing in essence with the array he defines.  But yes there is an error, I should have written `for(var i = 1; i < 8 ; i++)` if my assumption of replacing the array were to not impact the code any further.

Comment: Javascript arrays are 0-based. `i` should start at 0. Your correction would only loop 7 times, while the array has 8 elements.

Comment: However, there is a point of argument whether getting int values from an array is relevant, as OP could've used `i` instead of `array[i]`. In that case, you'd be right with your first correction.

Comment: I also changed the console.log for when the buttons are created, it's plain and simple to see that the listener/dialog function is being called before the actual buttons/html they correspond to. http://jsfiddle.net/3Tp35/2/

Answer (score 0):

Include the below code in document ready function

```
for(var i = 0; i < 7 ; i++) {
 $("#object").append("<button id=\opener"+array[i]+">Details</button> ");
 $("#object").append("<div class=\"dialog\" id=\"dialog"+array[i]+"\"title=\"Details\"></div>");
}
```

Comment: It seems it was left out intentionally, so it creates the dynamic elements *before* trying to perform the `.dialog()` on those elements. I see no reason why it *has to be* included in the doc.ready; could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap your loops over. At the moment you are trying to access `#dialogX` elements before they exist in the DOM. In fact, you can combine both loops into one, which creates the button and dialog elements and then instatiates the dialog.

```
var  array =['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'];

$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var $dialog = $('<div />', {
            class: 'dialog',
            id: 'dialog' + array[i],
            title: 'Details'
        }).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: "auto",
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 500
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 500
            }
        });

        var $button = $('<button />', {
            id: 'opener' + array[i],
            text: 'Details'
        }).click(function () {
            $("#dialog" + array[i]).dialog("open");
        });

        $("#object").append($button, $dialog);
    }
});
```

Comment: The order is not invertedin OP's example as far as I can see. The listeners are in the doc.ready, while the adding of dynamic elements is not (hence it gets executed first)